# Проблема запуска wordpress в docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

Пытаюсь запустить образ wordpress на хостинге от reg.ru по вот этому [туториалу](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/). Вроде бы все получилось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Перехожу на страничку http://5.63.154.209:8000/ все глухо, http://5.63.154.209/ тоже

Вот мой ifconfig 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что делаю не так?

Comment: не мала баба клопоту - решило докер замутить :). ВП запускается проще пареной репы - предварительно создав  вирируалхост с БД и залив файлы документрут достаточно открыть адрес в барузере и за 30 сек установить ВП :) Ида. ВП нужно брать из его репо, а не разных других

Comment: может быть, но хочется разобраться в докере

Comment: ВП тут не причем. Да и докер.. тем более на регру - зря потраченное время. Хочется разбираться с докером - лучше на виртуалку поставить. Но вообще его использование весьма специфично.. надо ли Лано, сорри. я увлёкся не буду мешать..Но ВП всё же не причём.

Comment: @SeVlad это все-таки не сайт народной мудрости, и участник предельно конкретен в своих вопросах.

Comment: Внешне все выглядит хорошо, кроме рестартующей базы (скорее всего, не указали MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD), но это не должно мешать запуску апача и выдаче ошибок уже от PHP. Есть небольшая вероятность, что рег.ру режет подключения на некоторых портах, которую хочется отсечь. Если вы переподнимите контейнер на порте 80, ситуация изменится?

Comment: @etki, было бы хорошо, если бы не было акцента на ВП и он не упоминался в метках. Из вопроса же не понятна реальная (конечная) цель -  разобраться с докером или развернуть ВП для дальнейшей работы. После объяснений стало понятно, что ВП тут никаким боком.Нет с ВП тут проблем и вопросов по нему.

Comment: @SeVlad http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535/16095

Comment: @etki, ещё раз: вопрос без уточнений был не понятный=некорректный. Метки (как выяснилось позже) неправильные (но не отредактированы до сих пор). Никакой злости и раздражения нет (с моей стороны, в отличии от.. :) ). См мой второй комент.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь, проблема была в том что wordpress требует mysql который падал из-за недостатка оперативной памяти (решилось увеличением свайпа). Имхо метка вордпресс нужна ибо специалисты в области вп могли помочь мне если у них были похожие преценденты